# Using openblas instead of blas breaks fltk - plotting in Octave

Tags: manjaro, plotting, octave

When I try to plot anything in GNU Octave, I get this error.

```
octave:1> plot(linspace(1,2,30),linspace(1,1,30))
error: feval: /usr/lib/octave/5.2.0/oct/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/__init_fltk__.oct: failed to load: libfltk_gl.so.1.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
error: called from
    graphics_toolkit at line 91 column 5
    figure at line 91 column 7
    newplot at line 117 column 10
    plot at line 222 column 9
```

One workaround is to use `gnuplot` instead of `fltk`, but the plots look better with `fltk`.

It turned out that `blas` was replaced by `openblas` during installing Julia, and after installing `blas` (by removing `julia` and `openblas`) it works again.

So, how to make `fltk` work with `openblas`?

Comment: The error message indicates an issue with loading the `libfltk_gl` library. This does not seem to be related to Blas vs. OpenBlas.

Comment: Yes, it seems things got messed up after installing julia. But after installing fltk, it works again. Then I install Julia. Now it works even after removing fltk. I have no idea why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by installing fltk with `sudo pacman -S fltk`.